# Problem in showing foreign key relation in view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-rest-viewsets

I have a `Land` model with three relation which one of them is `Letter` and the model is:

```
class Letter(models.Model):
    land = models.ForeignKey('Land', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to=letter_image_file_path)
    text = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```

and its serializer is

```
class LettersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Letter
    fields = ('id', 'text', 'image', 'land',)
    read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

and `Land` serializer is:

```
class LandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    utm_points = UTMPointsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    letters = LettersSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

their views are :

```
class BasicViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)


class LandViewSet(BasicViewSet):
    serializer_class = LandSerializer
    queryset = Land.objects.all()

class UTMPointViewSet(BasicViewSet):
    serializer_class = UTMPointsSerializer
    queryset = UTMPoint.objects.all()


class LettersViewSet(BasicViewSet):
    serializer_class = LettersSerializer
    queryset = Letter.objects.all()
```

but when I send `GET` request it doesn't show `letters` field: here is the response:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "utm_points": []
}
```

although `utm_points` and `letters` are exactly the same but they have different results.
`Land` model has `user` relation which I removed it as simplicity.
After some trials and errors I have no idea why the result does't have `letters` field.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain to the `LetterSerializer` what serializer to use to serialize `Land`. You can not use the `LandSerializer` since that would create a circular dependency but more important: possibly infinite recursion in the response since a `Letter` has a `land` and the `land then serializes its related` letters, etc.

We thus make a simple serializer for `Land`:

```
class SimpleLandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    utm_points = UTMPointsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Land
        fields = ['utm_points']
```

and then use this in the serializer for `land`:

```
class LettersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    land = SimpleLandSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Letter
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'image', 'land',)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

**EDIT**: You can also serialize by using the primary key, in that case you can serialize with a [**`PrimaryKeyRelatedField`** [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield):

```
class LettersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    land = PrimaryKeyRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Letter
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'image', 'land',)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

**EDIT 2**: Another problem is that your `letters` relation does not exists, if you want to rename the relation from `letter_set` to `letters`, you use:

```
class Letter(models.Model):
    land = models.ForeignKey(
        'Land',
        related_name='letters',
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING
    )
```

Comment: Actually I need to show  letters in land response but you suggest `LettersSerializer` should show land serializer, on the other hand Letter and UTMPoints are exactly the same. so how come just letter wont be shown?

Comment: @moslem: because that would result in a serialization *cycle* where if you serialize a `Letter`, you serialize its `land`, that `land` will then serialize new `Letter`s which will again serialize land, so the JSON would look like `{'land': {'letters': [{'land': ...}]}}` and thus result in a response of infinite length.

Comment: No `LettersSerializer` just serializes `id` of `Land` you can see it in the definition of the serializer and `utm` has exactly the same implementation but without any problem

Comment: Your `LettersSerializer` has as `fieldds = ('id', 'text', 'image', 'land')`...

Comment: Yes but it just serializes id this is the output `{
        "id": 2,
        "text": "test",
        "image": null,
        "land": 1
    },`

Comment: @moslem: ah in that case you can use a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`.

Comment: Thanks. but can you update the answer please

Comment: No, It doesn't work I need to serialize letters in land not land in letter it's already serialize land in letter without `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`

Comment: @moslem: but `letters` does not exists as a field. If you want to span a related field, you use `land = models.ForeignKey('Land', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='letters')`, otherwise it will use `letter_set`.